# Provide the ability to sort by two fields in a table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting

One of the pages of my site is made in the form of a table. The table has a header and a body. The table has several columns, and I would like to sort by two columns.

The essence of my idea is that the user would click on the button in the header and the location of the records in the body of the table would change. I tried several options, but they failed. Perhaps you can help me.

Below I will give an example code, with a little explanation.

```
export default function Records() {
    const [records] = useRecords(database)

    return (
            <Table>
                <TableBody>
                    {records.map((record) =>
                        <RecordsTableCell  key={record.id} />)}
                </TableBody>
            </Table>
    );
}
```

Can you please tell me how to set up sorting on two fields. I don't need them to depend on each other in any way. Simple: click on the button that corresponds to duration and get the result in ascending order, click again and get the result in descending order. Similarly, with a button that matches the timestamp

Comment: "I tried several options, but they failed" - please show your attempts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this - I have inlined the child components and used normal HTML tags instead of table components but this should give you an idea.

Click the table headings to see the sorting.

Further work (left as an exercise to the reader):

- change cursor over `<th>` elements
- display the current sorting direction in the table header
- get the `sort` function to work with strings as well
- multi-level sorting (sort by multiple columns at once)

```js
const RECORDS = [
  {id: 0, duration: 5, timestamp: 10},
  {id: 1, duration: 32, timestamp: 16},
  {id: 2, duration: 16, timestamp: 8},
];

function RecordsTable() {
    // demo data instead of hook
    const records = RECORDS;
    const [sortBy, setSortBy] = React.useState(null);
    
    // useMemo since sorting is relatively expensive
    const sortedRecords = React.useMemo(()=>{
      if(!sortBy){
        return records;
      }
      const {field, order} = sortBy;
      const factor = order === "asc" ? 1 : -1;
      // sort mutates the array, so let's copy it before sorting
      const newRecords = [...records];
      newRecords.sort((a, b)=>{return (a[field] - b[field]) * factor;});
      return newRecords;
    }, [records, sortBy]);
    
    const sort = (field) => {
      if(!sortBy || sortBy.field !== field){
        setSortBy({field, order: "asc"});
      } else {
        // we have already selected the same field, so switch the sorting to desc
        const {order} = sortBy;
        // TODO insert bad Star Wars joke
        const newOrder = order === "asc" ? "desc" : "asc";
        setSortBy({field, order: newOrder});
      }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <table>
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th onClick={()=>sort("duration")}>Duration</th>
                    <th onClick={()=>sort("timestamp")}>Timestamp</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {sortedRecords.map((record) => (
                      <tr key={record.id}>
                        <td>{record.duration}</td>
                        <td>{record.timestamp}</td>
                      </tr>
                    ))}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            
            <button onClick={()=>setSortBy(null)}>Reset sorting</button>
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<RecordsTable />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. There is only one caveat. I'm already trying to solve it, but so far to no avail: you fit the whole solution into one component, but I have two components. Could you still show an example of a solution on my components?

Comment: Just use your component instead of the HTML tags I am using. For example, replacing the existing `map` with `{sortedRecords.map((record) =>
                        <RecordsTableCell record={record} key={record.id} />)}` should work out of the box